# How to fix 'Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation X' of type X error in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 5 project using Entity Framework Core.

I have these entities

```
public class StudentTrainingMark
{
        public         int           Id              { get; set; }
        public         decimal       TheoreticalMark { get; set; }
        public         decimal       PracticalMark   { get; set; }
        public         string        Note            { get; set; }

        public         string        BranchId        { get; set; }
        public         byte          FormationYearId { get; set; } 
        public         string        StudentId       { get; set; }

        public virtual Branch        Branch          { get; set; }
        public virtual FormationYear FormationYear   { get; set; }
        public virtual Student       Student         { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{ 
    public string Id         { get; set; }
    public string FirstName  { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StudentTrainingMark>   StudentTrainingMarks { get; set; }
}
```

I created configuration profile for each entity to do some configs like required fields and relationships.

So `StudentTrainingMark` also has a config profile like this:

```
public class StudentTrainingMarkEntityConfig:IEntityTypeConfiguration<StudentTrainingMark>
{
    public void Configure( EntityTypeBuilder<StudentTrainingMark> builder )
    {
        builder.HasKey( x => x.Id );
        builder.Property( x => x.Id ).UseIdentityColumn();

        builder.Property( x => x.TheoreticalMark ).IsRequired();
        builder.Property( x => x.PracticalMark ).IsRequired();

        builder.Property( x => x.BranchId ).IsRequired();
        builder.Property( x => x.FormationYearId ).IsRequired();
        builder.Property( x => x.StudentId ).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

And `Student` also has a config profile like this:

```
public class StudentEntityConfig:IEntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
{
    public void Configure( EntityTypeBuilder<Student> builder )
    {
        builder.HasKey( x => x.Id );
        builder.Property( x => x.Id ).IsRequired();

        builder.Property( x => x.FirstName ).IsRequired();
        builder.Property( x => x.FamilyName ).IsRequired();
        builder.Property( x => x.BirthDate ).IsRequired();
        builder.Property( x => x.BirthPlace ).IsRequired();
        builder.Property( x => x.Gender ).IsRequired();
        builder.Property( x => x.Nationality ).IsRequired();
        builder.Property( x => x.Address ).IsRequired();
        builder.Property( x => x.DateOfRegistration ).IsRequired();
        builder.Property( x => x.AcademicYearOfRegistration ).IsRequired();
        builder.Property( x => x.StudentGuardianId ).IsRequired( false );

        builder.Property( x => x.StudyLevelId ).IsRequired();
        builder.Property( x => x.GroupId ).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

What is exactly the issue?

The issue is with all of this when I try to add new migration I get this error

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Student.TrainingMark' of type 'StudentTrainingMark'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Please - any help on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Your Student entity has only a Navigation Property `TrainingMarks`.  The error mentions  `Student.TrainingMark`.  So something doesn't add up.

Comment: Your other duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69243311/7758804) was just closed. In the future do not open the same question more than a single time.

Answer (score 0):

You can set ther relation:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<StudentTrainingMark>()
            .HasOne<Student>(s => s.Student)
            .WithMany(g => g.StudentTrainingMarks)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.StudentId);
```